# How can I capture all 307 redirects with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

[image: Cypress Logs]

I am trying to test that a backend redirect url includes a certain parameter in the URL that it sends to google auth login. I can see the URL I want to test in the cypress logs when using headed mode, however I can't seem to be able to get access to that URL to confirm it includes the required text because that url ends up redirecting to a different final URL which is the one that my line ends up testing (see the failed line in the screenshot).

Does anyone know how to get access to that middle URL in the redirect chain?

I tried using

```
cy.on('url:changed', (url) => console.log(url))
```

but it similarly skips to the last URL

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This had what I was looking for:

```
cy.request('/request/with/multiple/redirects')
  .then((response) => {
    response.redirects // redirect was in this array
  })
```